# System won't boot if I connect SATA hard disk

Tags: motherboard, upgrade, sata, boot

I had an old PC with an Atom processor, two SATA hard disks with 40 GB and 160 GB each.

Recently I upgraded my PC, got a Gigabyte H61M DS2 Motherboard, 2 GB of RAM and Core I3 processor.

But whenever I connect the power connector to my 40 GB hard disk, the computer shows no sign of power. Even the CPU fan does not move.

Fortunatley, my OS is on the 160 GB disk and everything works fine if I disconnect the power connector from the 40 GB hardisk.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the power supply like? Have you changed it from the original? It sounds like it's struggling.

Comment: Actually yes, i had changed my SMPS too.. as my old smps had failed. along with the motherboard. thats the reason i went for the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your power supply is not being able to power all your components, and that's why it works without one disk but it doesn't with both of them.

Comment: but if thats the case should'nt it work fine with only the 40 GB hard disk connected? let me try that today when i reach home.

Comment: Yes, I guess it should work if you only connect the 40 GB disk

Comment: No admenva, it does not work with only the 40GB hard disk too. i connected only the 40GB hard disk and tried. when i pressed the power button the power led just glow for a second and went off. the fan did not move either.